# How to display random media and images

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using my T3 4.5.10, and I would like ton insert randomly content from a sysfolder into a specific page.

So, I wrote a small TS:

```
lib.randomContent = COA_INT
lib.randomContent {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList = 10
            max = 1
            orderBy = rand()
        }
    }
}
```

I included that TS into my page. Page 10 is a folder containing "images" and "media". Medias are swf files.

All *images* are perfectly randomly displayed, but *media* are never displayed.

What should I do to display my medias?

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Hi you forgot "renderObj < tt_content" to uye standard renderign..

```
lib.randomContent = COA_INT
lib.randomContent {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList = 1
            max = 10
            orderBy = rand()
        }
        renderObj < tt_content
    }
}
```

Comment: renderObj < [tablename] is default. So if you do not define renderObj it will allways use the name of the table as object. So if you retrieve tt_address renderObj would use tt_address.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK some media objects (f.e. shockwaveflash) needs some JavaScript for initializing. I guess the HTML would be fine, but the JS is missing?

For testing you could deactivate caching for that page.

If i am right, you could do some workarounds:

1. change your COA_INT to an COA and change the cacing period of that page to one minute (page-settings)
2. include another media content element on that page (but hidden via CSS) (i would expect that this works too)
3. add the missing JS on your own (i guess typo3/contrib/flashmedia/swfobject/swfobject.js and typo3/contrib/flashmedia/swfobject/expressInstall.swf)